# Create multiple features from a single field

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro, one-to-many, explode

I have a point feature class showing addresses where trees were planted. A single row in the attribute table represents a single address. I have a field in the attribute table called "TOTAL_TREES_DISTRIBUTED" which tells me how many trees were planted at that address. What I'd like to do is transpose or explode? (not sure what the term is here) that "TOTAL_TREES_DISTRIBUTED" field into multiple point features for an address. For example, address 123 Main St has a value of 3 in the "TOTAL_TREES_DISTRIBUTED" field. Currently, my feature class shows 1 feature point at 123 Main St and 1 attribute table row with a value of 3 in the "TOTAL_TREES_DISTRIBUTED" field. Instead, I'd like 3 points located at 123 Main St and 3 rows each representing 1 single tree. So in essence, the way my table is designed is one-to-many...1 feature/row may represent multiple trees. Ideally, I'm looking to migrate this data into a one-to-one format...1 feature/row represents 1 tree. Any advice on how to do this? I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.5 but willing to tackle a workflow in ArcMap 10x or Excel. [image]